# Setting Layouts in ViewPagerIndicator?

Tags: android, viewpagerindicator

Hi there I am having a bit of struggle trying to use Jake's ViewPagerIndicator. My first problem is how can I set different layouts for different page in the ViewPagerIndicator ?.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        TextView text = new TextView(getActivity());
        text.setText("Hello!");
        text.setTextSize(20 * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);
        text.setPadding(20, 20, 20, 20);

        LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(getActivity());
        layout.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
        layout.addView(text);

    return layout;
}
```

I have edited the sample code very briefly but I do not know how to change layouts between different page swipes and I would also like to know how to set the id of the items that I am creating in the ViewPagerIndicator so I can make responses ?.
I have tried to say something like

```
text.onclicklistener
```

But I keep on having errors with this code. I am now also wondering whether or not I will have to set an ID of all my items that I create inside of his class. I also tried this but with no success. Do i have to use an ID in order to use the OnClickListener .etc?

`text.setId("android:id@hello");`

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do so by tweaking the code !

First comment this part:

```
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        builder.append(content).append(" ");
    }
    builder.deleteCharAt(builder.length() - 1);
```

Second add this: fragment.mContent = content; // below the loop

third you have to inflate your layouts inside onCreateView():

```
    View view=null;
    if(mContent.equals("title1"))
    {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.title1, container, false);

    }
    else if(mContent.equals("title2"))
    {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.title2, container, false);
    }
```

return view;